# Trying to display line chart using DataBindCrossTable method always bar chart appears

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, mschart

Iam trying to create a chart in asp.net using inbuilt chart controls ,I read the data from the sql using a stored proc and stored it in a list .When I use the datacrosstable always the barchart is displayed.I need the line chart to be displayed.

```
Chart1.DataBindCrossTable(mylist,"engine", "year", "value","Label=value");
```

In markup I had also specified

```
<asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server">
    <series>
        <asp:Series ChartType="Line" Name="Series1" />
    </series>
</asp:Chart>
```

also tried this in the cs page

```
Chart1.Series[0].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
Chart1.Series[1].BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DataBindCrossTable` creates a new series per unique value. So that `<asp:Series...` in your ASPX markup does not appply. You will have to set ChartType for each created series in code.

Comment: thanks adding this worked  foreach (Series cs in Chart1.Series)

{

cs.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

cs.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;



}